# Discord.py - How to use information from users who responded to the bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot that divides the people who choose the reaction of the bot into two teams and lists them.
I've just started studying Python, and I'm finding a bot with a similar function in the Github, and I'm making it a function I want by modifying it little by little.

- A person enters $divide.
- After the bot outputs a set sentence, add 'O' as a response.
- Users click on the 'O' response.
- The bot compiles the number of people who clicked 'O' and classifies them into two teams.
- List and print out the two teams classified.

When the corresponding command is executed, only Team A : and Team B : are printed out, not the list is created when I or someone else clicks the response while the bot counts.
I think the information of the person who clicked on the reaction of the bot is not being sent to the door when.
But I'm not sure about that, and if this is right, I don't know how to solve it with my current lack of skills.

to be in need of assistance

When the corresponding command is executed, only Team A : and Team B : are printed out, not the list is created when I or someone else clicks the response while the bot counts.
I think the information of the person who clicked on the reaction of the bot is not being sent to the door when.
But I'm not sure about that, and if this is right, I don't know how to solve it with my current lack of skills.

I need some help...

Here is my code :

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

DRAFT_COUNT = 10

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.command()
async def divide(ctx):
    ladder_agree.clear()
    ladder_team_a.clear()
    ladder_team_b.clear()

    ladder = await ctx.send("Would you like to join the team distribution?")
    await ladder.add_reaction("⭕")

    guide_text = await ctx.send("count : 30 sec")
    for i in range(0, DRAFT_COUNT):
        j = DRAFT_COUNT - i
        await guide_text.edit(content=f"count : {j} sec")
        time.sleep(1)
        if j == 1:
            await guide_text.edit(content="done")
            for k in range(0, len(entry)):
                if entry[k].startswith("⭕"):
                    ladder_agree.append(entry[k])

    while len(ladder_agree) > 0:
        temp1 = random.choice(ladder_agree)
        ladder_team_a.append(temp1)
        ladder_agree.remove(temp1)

        temp2 = random.choice(ladder_agree)
        ladder_team_b.append(temp2)
        ladder_agree.remove(temp2)

    text = ""
    for i in range(0, len(ladder_team_a)):
        text = text + ", " + ladder_team_a[i]
    await ctx.send("\n\n Team A : " + text)

    text2 = ""
    for i in range(0, len(ladder_team_b)):
        text2 = text2 + ", " + ladder_team_b[i]
    await ctx.send("\n\n Team B : " + text2)


@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    for i in range(0, len(entry)):
        if user.mention in entry[i]:
            switch = 1
            break
        else:
            switch = 0

    if switch == 0:             
        if user.bot == 1:       
            return None
        if str(reaction.emoji) == "⭕":
            entry.append("join/"+ user.mention)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what `ladder_agree`, `ladder_team_a` and `ladder_team_b` are, but I'm assuming these are global lists since they don't appear to be defined in your code. Use this as local ones, so they are defined and empty every time someone uses the command. It will also not "empty" the lists if someone uses the command again

For what you are trying to achieve, you don't need the `on_reaction` event. All you need is to get everyone who reacted with `⭕` in to a list, and divide them from there.

At the point of sending the message, `ladder`, it does not contain any reaction information. You need to fetch the message again to get the updated information that contains the reactions.

```py
@bot.command()
async def divide(ctx, DRAFT_COUNT:int=10): # Comment 1 after the code
    ladder_agree = []
    ladder_team_a = []
    ladder_team_b = []

    ladder = await ctx.send("Would you like to join the team distribution?")
    await ladder.add_reaction("⭕")

    guide_text = await ctx.send("count : " + str(DRAFT_COUNT) + " sec")
    while DRAFT_COUNT>=1:
        DRAFT_COUNT -= 1
        await guide_text.edit(content=f"count : {DRAFT_COUNT} sec")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    
    await guide_text.edit(content="done")
    ladder = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(ladder.id)
    ladder_agree = [u.mention for u in await ladder.reactions[0].users().flatten() if u != client.user]

    # If only one person enters, there is no point in sorting
    # Check comment 2 and 3 after the code
    if len(ladder_agree)>1:
        while len(ladder_agree) > 0:
            if len(ladder_agree)>0:
                temp1 = random.choice(ladder_agree)
                ladder_team_a.append(temp1)
                ladder_agree.remove(temp1)

            if len(ladder_agree)>0:
                temp2 = random.choice(ladder_agree)
                ladder_team_b.append(temp2)
                ladder_agree.remove(temp2)

        text = ""
        for i in range(0, len(ladder_team_a)):
            text = text + ladder_team_a[i] + ", " 
        await ctx.send("\n\n Team A : " + text)

        text2 = ""
        for i in range(0, len(ladder_team_b)):
            text2 = text2 + ladder_team_b[i] + ", "
        await ctx.send("\n\n Team B : " + text2)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Not enough entrants")
```

comments:

1. DRAFT_COUNT can be set during the command, `$divide 30` will set it to 30 seconds, not setting anything will automatically put it to only 10. You can remove that bit and write DRAFT_COUNT = 10 where you have the ladders
2. If there is only one person who enters, the bot will say whatever you put in the "else".
3. `while len(ladder_agree)>0` means that if you have an odd number of entrants, it will throw an error because it tries top pick "temp" from an empty list at some point. You can either use `while len(ladder_agree)>1` which means if you have an odd number, one person will not be sorted. Or you can put in an extra check that `if len(ladder_agree)>0`, only then try to pick temp1, and then again for temp2. In case of odd number entrants, team A will always get last member. A little cleaner way of processing the after getting the `ladder_agree` list is also at the end

Links to docs:

- [discord.Message.reactions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.reactions)
- [discord.Reaction.users](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Reaction.users)

A little cleaner way of doing the last bit, after getting the ladder_agree list

```py
    if len(ladder_agree)>1:
        a = int(len(ladder_agree)/2) 
        # Forcing a to be int and not float. int will round down if list is uneven. int(5.4) = 5, int(5.8) = 5
        
        # If list is uneven (odd number players), it's random what team gets to be one extra player
        if (len(ladder_agree) %2)!=0:
            print('list is uneven')
            p = random.randint(0,1)
            if p==1:
                a +=1
        
        # team_a list = select a amount of players from ladder_agree list
        ladder_team_a = random.sample(ladder_agree, a)

        # To put the rest in team_b
        ladder_team_b = ladder_agree
        for i in ladder_team_a:
            ladder_team_b.remove(i)

        # To generate the text strings and send the messages
        texta = ", ".join(i for i in ladder_team_a)
        textb = ", ".join(i for i in ladder_team_b)
        await ctx.send("Team A: " + texta)
        await ctx.send("Team B: " + textb)
    else:
        await ctx.send("Not enough entrants")
```

Comment: @TimeJ I've added a 2nd option you can do after  you get`ladder_agree`. Have a look at that as well. Also, if the solution worked for you, make sure to accept the answer so the question is marked as solved.